# Transforming array of objects containing arrays into a unique object lookup with lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

How would you transform `codes` into `result` using `lodash` ?

```js
const codes = [
   {a: 'aa', b: [ 8518 ], c: [ '2146' ]},
   {a: 'bb', b: [ 120123 ], c: [ 'D835', 'DD3B' ]},
   {a: 'cc', b: [ 168, 532 ], c: [ '00A8' ] }
]

const result = [
   {a: 'aa', b:8518, c:'2146'},
   {a: 'bb', b:120123, c:'D835'},
   {a: 'bb', b:120123, c:'DD3B'},
   {a: 'cc', b:168, c:'00A8'},
   {a: 'cc', b:532, c:'00A8'}
]
```

Comment: Why tag this with `ecmascript-6` when you want a lodash solution? I mean, with ecmascript-6 you really don't need lodash for such a task...

Comment: Because I want the answer to be written in modern ES6 syntax (spread operators, arrow functions, etc). I never said you NEED lodash to solve this, but we have an application to maintain with a lot of lodash function use and it makes sense to keep new functionality in the repo in the same flavour as the rest of the code - it will be more consistent. There are a lot of lodash users, this question can benefit them too. I can remove the tag if it means you'll remove your downvote! Surely it's my right to request a lodash answer with ES6 syntax if I want to? The question was clear.

Comment: Also, see this: https://derickbailey.com/2016/09/12/does-es6-mean-the-end-of-underscore-lodash/

Comment: I cannot remove a downvote, since I never downvoted this question. The accepted answer proves my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `Array.flatMap()` calls (or lodash's `_.flatMap()`) to iterate the main array, and the `b` objects , and `Array.map()` to iterate the `c` arrays to create an array of objects with all the combinations of `b` and `c` values:

```js
const codes = [{ a: 'aa', b: [8518], c: ['2146'] }, { a: 'bb', b: [120123], c: ['D835', 'DD3B'] }, { a: 'cc', b: [168, 532], c: ['00A8'] }]

const result = codes.flatMap(o =>
  o.b.flatMap(b => 
    o.c.map(c => ({ ...o, b, c }))
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

With plain Javascript you could separate the problem into two task, one for build a cartesian product of an array with a nested structure and another for mapping the part result of the cartesian products.

`getCartesian` is a recursive function which separates all key/value pairs and build a new cartesian product by iterating the values, if an array with objects call `getCartesian` again and build new objects.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var input =  [{ a: 'aa', b: [8518], c: ['2146'] }, { a: 'bb', b: [120123], c: ['D835', 'DD3B'] }, { a: 'cc', b: [168, 532], c: ['00A8'] }],
    cartesian = input.flatMap(o => getCartesian(o));

console.log(cartesian);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is great, but i prefer the more compact lodash answer. Thanks anyway, I'm sure it will help others!